# How can you efficiently build one ML model per partition in Spark with foreachPartition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to fit one ML model for each partition of my dataset, and I do not know how to do it in Spark.

My dataset is basically looking like this and **is partitioned by Company**:

```
Company | Features | Target

A         xxx        0.9
A         xxx        0.8
A         xxx        1.0
B         xxx        1.2
B         xxx        1.0
B         xxx        0.9
C         xxx        0.7
C         xxx        0.9
C         xxx        0.9
```

My goal is to train one regressor for each company, in a parallelised way (I have a few hundred millions of records, with 100k companies).
My intuition is that I need to use `foreachPartition` to have the partitions (i.e. my companies) processed in parallel and each company model trained and saved. **My main problem is about how to deal with `iterator` type that is to be used in the function called by `foreachPartition`.**

Here is what it would look like:

```scala
dd.foreachPartition(

    iterator => {var company_df = operator.toDF()
                 var rg = RandomForestRegressor()
                                 .setLabelCol("target")
                                 .setFeaturesCol("features")
                                 .setNumTrees(10)
                 var model = rg.fit(company_df)
                 model.write.save(company_path)
                 }
)
```

As I understand it, trying to convert the `iterator` into a `dataframe` is not a possibility since the concept of RDD is cannot exist by itself in a `foreachPartition` statement.

I know the question is quite open but I am really stuck.

Comment: I wonder if you came up with a solution on this problem ? I have exact same plan running  lightgbm for each state, if i put all in a for loop I lose parallelism, still not sure how can i utilize pandas_udf for each group with ML model in it.

Answer (score 2):

In pyspark you can do something like below

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
# df has four columns: id, y, x1, x2

group_column = 'id'
y_column = 'y'
x_columns = ['x1', 'x2']
schema = df.select(group_column, *x_columns).schema

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
# Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame
def ols(pdf):
    group_key = pdf[group_column].iloc[0]
    y = pdf[y_column]
    X = pdf[x_columns]
      X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

    return pd.DataFrame([[group_key] + [model.params[i] for i in   x_columns]], columns=[group_column] + x_columns)

beta = df.groupby(group_column).apply(ols)
```

Comment: Very useful if I switch to PySpark. Any equivalent in Scala Spark?

Comment: Pandas is a python library and there are ways you can use something like JNI to use the equivalent in Scala but it would be very convoluted to implement. I would say that sticking to PySpark will be the cleanest solution.