# Training ml models on spark per partitions. Such that there will be a trained model per partition of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

How to do parallel model training per partition in spark using scala?
The solution given here is in Pyspark. I'm looking for solution in scala.
[How can you efficiently build one ML model per partition in Spark with foreachPartition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592081/how-can-you-efficiently-build-one-ml-model-per-partition-in-spark-with-foreachpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the distinct partitions using partition col
2. Create a threadpool of say 100 threads
3. create future object for each threads and run

sample code may be as follows-

```
   // Get an ExecutorService 
    val threadPoolExecutorService = getExecutionContext("name", 100)
// check https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/shared/HasParallelism.scala#L50

   val uniquePartitionValues: List[String] = ...//getDistingPartitionsUsingPartitionCol
    // Asynchronous invocation to training. The result will be collected from the futures.
    val uniquePartitionValuesFutures = uniquePartitionValues.map(partitionValue => {
      Future[Double] {
        try {
            // get dataframe where partitionCol=partitionValue
            val partitionDF = mainDF.where(s"partitionCol=$partitionValue")
          // do preprocessing and training using any algo with an input partitionDF and return accuracy
        } catch {
          ....
      }(threadPoolExecutorService)
    })

    // Wait for metrics to be calculated
    val foldMetrics = uniquePartitionValuesFutures.map(Await.result(_, Duration.Inf))
    println(s"output::${foldMetrics.mkString("  ###  ")}")
```